# Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'UISegmentedControl' from 'NSString'

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a `UISegmentedControl` in my iOS app, and depending on which button is selected, I want `self.itemLocation` to either be assigned a value of "US" or "Worldwide".

Xcode however, is telling me that an NSString is incompatible with this kind of button. How can I properly assign these values?

```
- (IBAction)itemLocation:(id)sender {

    switch (self.itemLocation.selectedSegmentIndex) {

        default:
        case 0:
            self.itemLocation = @"US";
            break;

        case 1:
            self.itemLocation = @"Worldwide";
            break;
    }

}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Change the title of one of the segments?

Comment: You can't assign an `NSString` to a `UISegmentedControl`. Look at the docs for `UISegmentedControl`. There are methods for setting the title of the segments.

Comment: This looks like an infinite loop?

Comment: @Hyperbole I don't think so, because `self.itemLocation` would call `itemLocation`, while `self.itemLocation = …` would call `setItemLocation:`.  This method is called `itemLocation:`, and the colon makes a difference.

Comment: It is most certainly NOT an infinite loop. Setting self.property certainly does not trigger an `IBAction` unless you have overridden the setter.

Comment: Infinite loop? There is no loop in the code.

Comment: @NobodyNada Ah, how gross of me to miss that.

Comment: I've set the titles of the segments in storyboard, what I want to do is set a value for self.itemLocation, depending on which segment is pressed. Not sure why I'm getting so many downvotes, did I not format the question properly?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming self.itemLocation is the UISegmentedControl then you can set the text of each segment as follows:

```
[self.itemLocation setTitle: @"Title" forSegmentAtIndex: 0];
```